# Table using array

Tags: tables, arrays

I'm creating Latex Tables using Array
One of the sample table is mentioned below with merging multi-cell of rows.

[image]

Can you please help me to understand, how can i merges rows in arrays
Sample Latex table with Array is mentioned below;

```
\[\begin{array}{*{20}{|c}}
\hline
   {{\text{Differentiation}}} & {{\text{Integration}}} & {}  \\
   {{\text{The problem of finding SLOPE}}} & {} & {}  \\
   {} & {{\text{Leibnitz}}} & {{\text{Archimedes}}}  \\
   a & b & c  \\
   d & e & f  \\
   g & h & i  \\
   j & k & l  \\
   m & n & o  \\
\hline
\end{array} \]
```

Comment: Off-topic (for this question): You don't need 20 columns; You don't need all the braces/`\text{Leibnitz}` would suffice; Why a textual table inside a math display equation?

Comment: Dear Sir, text mentioned above is dummy; table is having around 18 rows. I pasted image and array with rough data. Regarding table inside a math display equation; I'm looking for tools using which even person without latex knowledge can practically work with it. In MathType there is a option to convert display code into Latex commands; so textual table is inside a math display equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a starting point for you. I created a new column type `P` which makes it easier distributing the columns over the width of the textblock, because with this solution the widths of the `n` columns should add up to `1` and not to `1-n*\tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{P{0.3}P{0.35}P{0.35}}
    \toprule
    Differentiation & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Integration} \\
    \midrule
    Slope & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Area} \\
    & Leibnitz & Archimedes, Eudoxus, others \\
    & Anti Deri & Area \\
    & Test 1 & Test 2 \\
    & Indefinite Integral & Definite Integral \\[\baselineskip]
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Together constitutes Integral Calculus} \\
    \midrule
    Derivative of a polynomial function decreases its degree by 1 & \multicolumn{2}{p{0.5\textwidth}}{Integral of a polynomial function increases its degree by 1} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image]